# In C#, How to use Selected Index with Combobox and Textbox

Tags: c#, sql, database, combobox, textbox

Using selectedIndexChange for Combobox to fill Textboxes in Access Database.

I've tried using the following:

```
txtEventDate.Text = cboEventName.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

but it doesn't fill in from the selected data.

```
// clear out listbox
cboEventName.Items.Clear();

// create instance of class
clsData myData = new clsData();

// send SQL statement to class
myData.SQL = "SELECT ID, EventName, EventDate FROM tblEvents ORDER BY EventName";

// loop through datatable to get values
for (int i = 0; i < myData.dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    // add customer to list box
    cboEventName.Items.Add(myData.dt.Rows[i]["EventName"].ToString());
    // add customer id to list
    string eventdate = ["EventDate"].ToString();
    txtEventDate.Text = cboEventName.SelectedValue.ToString();
    // txtEventDate trying to fill from combobox entry and it isn't showing the date from the access.
    intEventID.Add(int.Parse(myData.dt.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString()));
}
```

Comment: if your "EventDate" is coming from mydate. Then set your myData.dt.Rows[i]["EventDate"].ToString()

Comment: Please add breakpoint and check every line. And see mydata has some data list and cboEventName is filling. Then check eventDate you are getting value before setting txtEventDate

Comment: I"m able to get the combobox to fill but the date will not populate the text field.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and the combobox doesn't fill in but the Event Date does with one solid date instead of based on the selection from the combobox

Comment: Inside your foreach condition add one more if condition to match with your selected index for combo box then set your eventdate(string) field. Now it is setting for each data from Mydata list.

Comment: I am missing something sorry how would I do this?

Comment: if( cboEventName.SelectedValue.ToString() == myData.dt.Rows[i]["EventName"].ToString()) string eventdate = ["EventDate"].ToString();

Comment: I have added the code in Answer. Give a try.

Comment: Is my solution works? or Still you have some issues or error.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this to set EventDate for Selected Index value. If SelectedValue is Matching to MyData Row Index then set event Date.

```
for (int i = 0; i < myData.dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                // add customer to list box
                cboEventName.Items.Add(myData.dt.Rows[i]["EventName"].ToString());
                // add customer id to list
                if(cboEventName.SelectedValue.ToString() ==myData.dt.Rows[i]["EventName"].ToString())
                    string eventdate = ["EventDate"].ToString();
                txtEventDate.Text = cboEventName.SelectedValue.ToString();
            }
```

Comment: hmmm ok however I am getting an error at the string eventdate = []. It says '[' Invalid Expression.  Am I missing something extra in this statement?

Comment: Modify your eventdate code like this. string eventdate =myData.dt.Rows[i] ["EventDate"].ToString();

Comment: would I use the string and have it point to the txtEventDate.Text? Something like txtEventDate.Text = eventdate? and then it should work

Comment: It now errors at the if (cboEventName...) states Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: Which line throw the error in your code. Do the breakpoint and check first. Also check you are getting value for cboEventName.SelectedValue.ToString().

Comment: The event name is filling the combobox. where my error is being thrown at is here:                 if (cboEventName.SelectedValue.ToString() == myData.dt.Rows[i]["EventName"].ToString()) <-- this line
                {
                    string eventdate = myData.dt.Rows[i]["EventDate"].ToString(); < to me this line does nothing.
                    txtEventDate.Text = eventdate;//cboEventName.SelectedValue.ToString();
                    intEventID.Add(int.Parse(myData.dt.Rows[i]["ID"].ToString()));
                }
            }

Comment: Sorry. Past few days i was on vacation. Have you fixed the issue. First set the combo box value, then check the selected value and compare the row from the list to get the event date.